# Empty list returned from XML query

Tags: xml, xquery, basex

Suppose I have a simple XML document organized according to this DTD

```
<!ELEMENT bids (bid_tuple*)>
<!ELEMENT bid_tuple (userid, itemno, bid, bid_date)>
<!ELEMENT userid (#PCDATA)>
<!ELEMENT itemno (#PCDATA)>
<!ELEMENT bid (#PCDATA)>
<!ELEMENT bid_date (#PCDATA)>
```

I've pasted a sample dataset [here](https://pastebin.com/C8mCcmmw).

The following query returns an empty list

```
for $i in distinct-values(//itemno)
  let $c := count(//bid_tuple[itemno = $i])
  let $av := avg(//bid_tuple[itemno = $i]/bid)
  where $c > 2      
  return $av
```

while if I replace the return statement with

```
return <a>{$av, $c} </a>
```

the correct values are returned (even if badly formatted obviously).
Again, something like

```
return <a>{$av} </a>
```

returns an empty list.

Is there any point that I'm missing here? I know that in all these cases the coders (i.e. me) are to blame, but could it be a problem with the `BaseX` implementation?

Comment: Consider to add a small but complete XML input sample that demonstrates the problem, together with information about which version of BaseX exactly you use.

Comment: I tried the sample shown in https://xqueryfiddle.liberty-development.net/nbUY4kj which there with Saxon 9.8  gives 150 also with BaseX 9.0.2 GUI and it also returns 150.

Comment: @MartinHonnen I can confirm that the problem is with BaseX 9, the latest version of BaseX 8 works without problems. I've also added the dataset as requested.

Comment: It seems BaseX 9 has a bug there, when I inline the document with `declare context item := document { ... };` and your query the right result is returned with the optimized query `for $i_0 in distinct-values(document {  }/descendant::itemno) where (2.0000000000000004 <= count(document {  }/descendant::bid_tuple[(itemno = $i_0)])) return avg(document {  }/descendant::bid_tuple[(itemno = $i_0)]/bid)` , when I use `declare context item := doc('file.xml');` I get, as you, no result.

Comment: I guess you will have to wait until a member of the BaseX picks this up.

Comment: As an alternative formulation which might even be more efficient and which works with BaseX 9.0.2 you could try `for $bid_tuple in //bid_tuple group by $no := $bid_tuple/itemno where count($bid_tuple) > 2 return avg($bid_tuple/bid)`

Comment: Thanks for the observation. The bug was fixed, this is the link to the latest stable snapshot: http://files.basex.org/releases/latest/. The path in the count expression is rewritten to an index access, `$c` is inlined, the `where` clause is rewritten to a predicate, and the resulting filter expression is rewritten to `if/then/else` (and the last optimization was invalid in this particular case).